# Nonlinear continuous system function of IMU sensor fusion robot

Tags: imu, matlab, ekf, sensor-fusion

For my robotics course I have to implement the nonlinear continuous system function for a mobile robot that is equipped with a GPS receiver and an IMU consisting of an accelerometer and a gyroscope. For the prediction step with an EKF, I need to implement the kinematic model $\dot x = f(x,u)$ with given state vector $x = \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\\v_x\\v_y\\v_z\\q_1\\q_2\\q_3\\q_4\end{pmatrix}$, input vector $u = \begin{pmatrix}a_x\\a_y\\a_z\\w_x\\w_y\\w_z\end{pmatrix}$, time $t$ and gravity $g$.

Afterwards, I need to calculate the matrix $A=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} $ and $B=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} $ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{10x10}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{10x6}$. These are used to calculate the system matrices $F$ and $H$ of the time discrete system (this is already given as Matlab code).

Unfortunately I didn't attend any control theory courses yet and it is my first semester in robotics, so I am pretty lost with this task. Maybe someone could give me a hint on how I have to approach this problem.

Comment: You should have the differential equations of your system somewhere. Those are the input and the state vector. With those information only, you cannot go anywhere. Can you post all the equations, you have?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, exzoran. How are you expecting to implement a continuous function for a system that's using discrete feedback? A GPS and IMU device will each provide samples on some update interval. It's also not clear what you're actually asking about here. You say you have to `implement the [...] function` and then you say you `need to calculate the matrix A [...] and B`. Are you doing system identification? I (and I'm sure others) would love to help, but realistically the best person you're going to find for help on this is your TA, lab supervisor, professor, etc.

Comment: @Dave I am only given the equations i already posted. u ist the input vector coming from the IMU and x is the state vector. On top of that I am only given the output vector of the GPS-reciever, but i thought this one wasn´t necessary for the task

Comment: @Chuck sorry if I wasn´t clear enough. The task is to implement the nonlinear time-continuous system diefferential equation $\dot x = f(x,u)$ of the kinematic model with the given parameters to linearize it. Afterwards I am asked to to implement the matrices $A$ and $B$ which are then used to calculate the system matrices $F$ and $H$ of the time-discrete system (those are already given). I hope this gives you more information

Comment: @exzoran Dear exzoran, we would like to help you, but there are two possibilities:
1) part of the task in incomplete, because you need the $f(x,u)$ somehow... otherwise you cannot calculate $\matrix{A}$. Maybe the task referes to a previous task done months/weeks ago?
2) the task requests something different than calculating the matrix $\matrix{A}$
I don't see any other possibilities

Comment: I re-read your question again. To me, you have to search for the equation system for the positions $x, y, z$, the velocities $v_{x}, v_{y}, v_{z}$ and the quaternions for the rotation $q_{1}, q_{2}, q_{3}, q_{4}$. Take a look here: https://charlestytler.com/quadcopter-equations-motion/ (I suppose, we are talking about a multicopter)

Comment: @Dave your second comment seams like what I am looking for. As far as I understood it, the robot I am dealing with is just a simulation of a "mobile platform" with 6 dimensions of freedom for movement in $x,y,z$ and and rotations on these axes. The problem is I have no idea on how to create this equation system. My guess is to use something like this: $\dot{x} = f(x,u) = \begin{pmatrix}a_x*t+v_x\\a_y*t+v_y\\a_z*t+v_z\\a_x\\a_y+g\\a_z\\?\\?\\?\\?\end{pmatrix}$, but I am not sure if this is right and how i have to calculate the quaternions

Comment: @exzoran Again... IF you are dealing with a simulation AND you are free to choose which dynamic system you prefered (the only contrain is that it must have 6 Degrees of Freedom), THEN you should search for a paper like that one I posted to you. In those papers there are dynamic system equation, which express the system in a state-space form. From there you can get the matrices, you need. Your guess is almost rigth but still too easy. Yes you have to implement quaternion. Again, do not reinvent the wheel, just find some papers. It is everything already done.

Comment: @exzoran Since you are dealing with 6 DoF a multicopter could be the best choice for you